# C - Speeding Up Binary File IO

Tags: c, optimization, memory, binaryfiles

I'm currently using the following code to parse a binary file byte by byte to look for occurrences of 0x44 0x44 0x53 0x20. The files range from 100 to 500 mb.

```c
int main() {
    ...
    FILE *f = fopen(name, "rb");

    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(f);
    parse_file(f, size);
    ...
}

void parse_file(FILE *f, int size) {
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    int read = 0;
    int count = 0;

    uint8_t *buf = malloc(size);
    fread(buf, sizeof(uint8_t), size, f);
    while (read < size - sizeof(uint32_t)) {
        if (*(buf + read) == 0x44) {
            if (*(buf + read + 1) == 0x44) {
                if (*(buf + read + 2) == 0x53) {
                    if (*(buf + read + 3) == 0x20) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        printf("\r%d/%d (%.2f%%)", read, size, (double)read / size);
        read += sizeof(uint8_t);
    }
    free(buf);
    buf = NULL;
}
```

The first file is 105mb and it only processes ~0.01% per minute. This seems much slower then I would have expected. Is it possible to optimize the code to speed the process up significantly? I'm using MinGW_64 on Windows 10 with 16gb of memory (at 33% usage with program running)

EDIT:
Code I was using before which was only slightly slower:

```c
while (read < (size - sizeof(uint32_t))) {
    uint32_t bytes;
    fread(&bytes, sizeof(uint32_t), 1, f);
    if (bytes == 0x44445320) {
        count++;
    }
    fseek(f, -(sizeof(uint8_t)*3), SEEK_CUR);
    read += sizeof(uint8_t);
    printf("\r%d/%d (%.2f%%)", read, size, (double)read / size);
}
```

Comment: Do not read the whole file into memory at once. Read in some reasonable size blocks, such as 4096 bytes. If your memory use really is low, this might not make a difference, but there is some possibility reading the entire file into memory causes allocation of virtual memory for your process, swapping of other memory to disk, and swapping of your process’ memory to disk at times. And it is simply unnecessary. Another option, besides reading some reasonable size block at a time, is to memory map the file (a la Unix’ `mmap`, but I do not know what the Windows equivalent is).

Comment: Note that using `ftell` to get the size and then reading that is error prone because a file may change size between the `ftell` and the read. Proper procedure is to read until EOF is encountered.

Comment: @EricPostpischil they would use the [File Mapping API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/file-mapping) which is what I would actually suggest unless they want to use [`OVERLAPPED` IO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/overlapped-operations) on windows.

Comment: That's reasonable speed assuming your file is stored on a dial-up service in Lithuania.  If its local it should take no more than a few seconds.

Comment: Incidentally, do not write `*(buf + read + 3)`; use `buf[read+3]`. It is much more readable. I would expect reading from disk to be the bottleneck, but the byte-by-byte testing is suboptimal. [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer–Moore_string-search_algorithm) may be a better algorithm, although in this case, the target string may be too short for it to help much. You do not have to understand the entire Boyer-Moore algorithm for this single case: Observe, if instead of examining `buf[read+0]`, `buf[read+1]`, and `buf[read+2]`, you examine `buf[read+3]`…

Comment: …. If it is not 0x44, 0x53, or 0x20, then the target string cannot start at `buf[read+0]`, or `+1`, `+2`, or `+3`. So you can just skip ahead to `buf[read+7]` and check whether it is any of those characters. If not, skip again. If it is, where you look next depends on which character it is.

Comment: Nonetheless, as noted, that speed, around 10,000 bytes/minute, is atrocious. Something else is going on in your program or system. Diagnosing that is what you should do first. Try a program that just reads the file without doing anything else. Does it also run slowly? Edit the question to show a [mre].

Comment: That's also a lot of opportunity for branch prediction fails... like most things involving performance I'd say start by profiling

Comment: @Mgetz: The code already contains byte-by-byte tests, so the missed prediction opportunities are already there. We are actually trying to reduce them by skipping tests we can determinate are not needed.

Comment: The file is read in almost instantly. Before I settled on the code I posted I was reading the file 4 bytes at a time and then going back 3 which was slightly slower but not by much.

Comment: BTW, I would read the files by chunks of fixed size, and try to use `memchr` and `memcp` which might be more optimized than  plain C loops. You must be cautious on what could happen if the searched string is splitted between 2 consecutive blocs, but it should not be worse than a handful of additional tests per chunk.

Comment: I could reproduce the slow performance on a linux system with `-O3 -march=native`

Comment: @JCWasmx86 thanks for testing that. I was just about to copy over the files and run it on my Ubuntu partition.

Comment: @Jim how fast does it go if you remove the `printf` ?

Comment: @Mgetz I started that but only waited about a minute. I no longer had any way to gauge the point it was at.

Comment: @Jim the reason I ask is because the code as posted [doesn't do any logic other than the printf](https://godbolt.org/z/9nvd44) once optimization is turned on because the method doesn't return `count`. The godbolt I've linked is what the method should compile to if the count is returned. So logically the only thing that could slow the current code is `printf`

Comment: It's now progressing at a rate of 0.1% every 5s on the same machine on Unix. Still far from ideal but it is faster

Comment: @Mgetz After switching to Linux and removing the print, it's now going at 1 file every couple seconds. That seemed to do the trick.

Comment: @Jim so `printf` is extraordinarily expensive. If you need tracking output I'd suggest doing it every 4-8% or so and avoiding `printf` as much as possible. There are other ways to speed this up by doing larger chunks. I suspect your original loop could actually be faster without the `printf` for example, but you'd have to profile. Note the 4-8% reason is so you can use a mod options and so it can be easily optimized by the compiler.

Comment: @Jim one last note... the `fread` you're doing is causing undefined behavior in the loop following as you're only reading a single byte.